# Spring Test for Controller Returns HTTP403 despite providing roles using @WithMockUser

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-security

I am struggling with the setup of a Rest Controller test due to Spring Security.

I am trying to test a basic rest endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/product")
public class ProductInformationController {

  private final ProductInformationService productInformationService;

  ...

  @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteProductById(@PathVariable int id) {
    productInformationService.deleteProductById(id);

    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
  }
```

The basic smoke test looks as follows:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebMvcTest({ProductInformationController.class, CommonControllerAdvice.class})
class ProductInformationControllerTest {

  private static final String SINGLE_RESOURCE_ENDPOINT_URL = "/product/{id}";

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  ProductInformationService service;

  ...

  @Test
  @WithMockUser(roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
  void shouldReturn204ForDeleteProduct() throws Exception {
    var productId = 1;
    
    mockMvc.perform(delete(SINGLE_RESOURCE_ENDPOINT_URL, productId))
        .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
  }
```

I have Spring Security among the dependencies but the configuration that exposes the `SecurityFilterChain` as a `@Bean` is not among the classes that are loaded for this WebMvcTest.

However, even despite having added both theoretically possible User Roles the test returns a HTTP 403 and does not even propagate the call to any handler:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = DELETE
      Request URI = /product/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@7ba1cdbe, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]]]}

Handler:
             Type = null
...

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Forbidden
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Manual tests of the endpoint work as expected. Any tests using GET work as expected as well, other HTTP verbs run into the same issue.

I assume the issue is the partial setup of Spring Security here. Since I only want to test the Controller I don't want to include the entire Spring Security configuration.

How can I make this controller test work with the most minimal set of other classes and a most lean application context?

Answer (score 0):

I think I stumbled across the same issue. As a solution I conditionally added some dummy users to the security chain.

As a base for mvc tests with Spring-Security as of Spring-Boot version 2.7.0 I made this abstract base class:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.RequestPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class AbstractMvcTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port;

    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private static final SimpleGrantedAuthority USER_AUTHORITY = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER");
    private static final SimpleGrantedAuthority ADMIN_AUTHORITY = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN");

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    protected RequestPostProcessor makeAuthorizedAdminUser() {
        return SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(new User(
                "Admin@example.com",
                passwordEncoder.encode("verys3cur3"),
                List.of(ADMIN_AUTHORITY, USER_AUTHORITY)));
    }

    protected RequestPostProcessor makeAuthorizedUser() {
        return SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(new User(
                "User@example.com",
                passwordEncoder.encode("foobar123"),
                List.of(USER_AUTHORITY)));
    }

}
```

A concrete test would look like this:

```java
class IndexControllerTest extends AbstractMvcTest
{
    @Autowired
    private IndexController controller;

    @Test
    void contextLoads()
    {
        assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void userLoggedIn_returnOk() throws Exception
    {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")
                        .with(makeAuthorizedUser()))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Where indexController just returns serves an index.html under root.